# Element from loaders list should have 'loader' or 'loaders' with sass-loader webpack

Tags: sass, loader, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-style-loader

I have this loader in my webpack loader array:

```
{ test: /\.scss$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ExtractTextPlugin('style-loader', 'css-loader!sass-loader') }
```

I am trying to have webpack build my SCSS to CSS but I am getting this error:

```
/Users/bli1/Development/Django/CL/cherngloong/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/LoadersList.js:60
    throw new Error("Element from loaders list should have one of the fields 'loader' or 'loaders'");
    ^

Error: Element from loaders list should have one of the fields 'loader' or 'loaders'
    at getLoadersFromObject (/Users/bli1/Development/Django/CL/cherngloong/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/LoadersList.js:60:8)
    at LoadersList.<anonymous> (/Users/bli1/Development/Django/CL/cherngloong/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/LoadersList.js:78:12)
    at Array.map (native)
    at LoadersList.match (/Users/bli1/Development/Django/CL/cherngloong/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/LoadersList.js:70:19)
    at NormalModuleFactory.<anonymous> (/Users/bli1/Development/Django/CL/cherngloong/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:109:65)
    at /Users/bli1/Development/Django/CL/cherngloong/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:697:13
    at /Users/bli1/Development/Django/CL/cherngloong/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at done (/Users/bli1/Development/Django/CL/cherngloong/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:248:21)
    at /Users/bli1/Development/Django/CL/cherngloong/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at /Users/bli1/Development/Django/CL/cherngloong/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:694:17
```

Here is my full webpack config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './app/index'
  ],

  output: {
      path: path.resolve('./public/bundles/'),
      filename: "[name]-[hash].js",
  },

  plugins: [
    new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),
  ],

  module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.css$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'style!css' },
        { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
        { test: /\.jsx$/, loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader'], include: path.join(__dirname, 'app') },
        { test: /\.es6$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader?stage=0&optional=runtime'},
        { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader?stage=0&optional=runtime'},
        { test: /\.scss$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ExtractTextPlugin('style-loader', 'css-loader!sass-loader') }
    ]
  },
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sokra has provided an example of how to use the ExtractTextPlugin here: https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin/blob/master/example/webpack.config.js

As you can see, there are some differences between your example and his.

- The ExtractTextPlugin constructor is called with *new* inside the "plugins: [ ]" array
- The way the plugin is used in the loaders array is by calling the static method .extract(), rather than simply calling the plugin constructor
- The reference in the "loader object" is for the "loade**r:**" property, rather than "loade**rs:**" as you have put (loaders is an option but expects an array)

Hope that helps!

Comment: I did not see the `extract()` I was too tired. Thanks! I needed another set of eyes!!

Comment: No problem, happy to help

Comment: I ran into a few more problems =[ If you want to take a shot at them I would really appreciate it thanks! [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328898/404-because-of-restarting-the-webpack-dev-server) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33324553/babel-trying-to-load-less-style-with-webpack)